# Implement video editor

Tags: c++, wpf, video, ffmpeg, directx

I want to implement a "simple" video editor and since I'm new to the topic, I'm not sure how to start.

The editor should have the following features / components

- A timeline for multiple recordings
- A video player that plays the edited video in real-time (it should render all added effects and assets)
- Assets that can be placed on the timeline such as text elements, arrows and so on

I'd like to start with the video player and then build the other components around it.

Which frameworks would you recommend?

For the player, I'm not sure if DirectShow is the right choice or MediaFoundation would be better. Are there other libraries to consider? FFmpeg?

Comment: Learn C++, video editing formats, the fundamentals of GUI programming, and your operating system's multimedia libraries. See you in a couple of years, good luck...

Comment: I'm not a beginner, have quite some experience with C++, GUI programming, OS, etc.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation given your interests is to start with Blender

http://www.blender.org

It's written in a combination of C, C++, and Python, has a substantial user community, and has the advantage of open source code so you can see how a real large project looks.

You might end up just contributing to it, or you might lift bits of it to bootstrap your own project, etc. But if you don't know about, it's worthwhile to look at if only to help you refine what you want to work on.